# How do the conditions for validation in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Just sorry for the dumb question , I know what it is in the documentation . But the documentation does not normally understand how to implement it .

Let's say there is a rule :

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|max:15',
            'author' => 'required|max:15',
        ];
    }
```

and it is usually used in the form " Edit " , say the user when editing a product , exceeded character limit of 15 , then leave the message " You have exceeded the character limit ."

PS please show a simple example , he 'll take care of that next to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [this link in the docs.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-error-messages)

As the docs say, define an array of messages that map to the rules, and pass them into the validator. Like so

```
$rules = [ 'title' => 'max:15' ]    
$msgs = [ 'max' => 'Exceeded char limit or whatever!' ]
Validator::make($input, $rules, $msgs);
```

Comment: On the second line, instead of `title`, it should be `max`, but otherwise this is correct.

Comment: @AdamKelso I changed it. It's been a while since I did some laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using FormRequest for validation. In that case you can add another method named `messages()` to your request class and return the custom messages from there, following is the example:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'required'  =>  'The attribute: field cannot be left blank',
    ];
```

The above example will replace the standard error message `the attribute: field is required.` with our custom message for all occurrences of `required` rule, where the `attribute:` denotes the name of the field under validation.

But if you want to further customise it on per field basis. You can use the dot (.) notation like this:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'title.required'  =>  'The Title must be filled',
    ];
```